# Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine. code=exited, status=217/User

Tags: 16.04, mssql

after an apt-get upgrade last week, i have failed to get my server back up and running again.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.18-2-pve x86_64).

running `systemctl status mssql-server` shows that the service is loaded and enabled but inactive due to `status=217/User`

I couldnt find anything about this error (except for systemd but im not sure if this has anything to do with mssql-server)

i have no idea how to resolve this issue.

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this problem?

When typing `systemctl start mssql-server`it prompts me for a password because it needs authentication. it wont let me chose a username but the username looked like `Thomas,1,-,-,- (thomas)`could that be the source of the problem? (it does look like illegal characters and im not sure how to change that username or if that piece is of any significance.

Answer (score 2):

i have no idea what the actual problem was, but i fixed it by running `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`again, chose the version and the password anew and suddenly it ran again.. maybe there was a wrong username, wrong password... maybe the license somehow expired or.. i dont know. all i know is it now works again.